# Connection between quadratic forms and ideal class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I'm studying the classic results on binary (integer) quadratic forms and I'm looking for a reference on the following result (maybe a book that contains a proof):

Let $O_k$ be the ring of algebraic integers of $Q(\sqrt{d})$. In the set of ideals of $O_k$, we define the equivalence relation $I \sim J \Leftrightarrow \exists a,b : (a)I=(b)J$ where $(a)$ is the ideal generated by $a$. Then, the equivalence classes of $\sim$ form a group $G$ with the usual multiplication of ideals. Furthermore, $|G|=h(d)$, where $h(d)$ is the class number.

The definition I've read for $h(d)$ is the number of equivalence classes of quadratic forms with discriminant $d$ for the equivalence relation $f \sim  g \Leftrightarrow f(x,y)=g(px+qy,rx+sy)$ with $ps-qr=1$.

If someone could give me a good reference in this nice connection I would be really grateful.

Comment: Does http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410184/whats-a-better-way-to-see-the-gausss-composition-law-for-binary-quadratic-form answer your question?

Comment: have you checked Cohen's a course in computational algebraic number theory?

Comment: See Theorem 5.30 of Cox's book on Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$.  The book in general discusses lots of things on binary quadratic forms and algebraic number theory.

Comment: Your definition needs to require $a$ and $b$ nonzero...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a concise account in the Appendix of these [notes](http://www.renyi.hu/~gharcos/heegner.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

A very thorough (although a bit dense) modern treatment is given in the article of Einsiedler, Lindenstrauss, Michel and Venkatesh about the ergodic theoretical proof of Duke's theorem (which is not unrelated to Gergely's notes) - [http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~elon/Publications/Erg-Duke.pdf](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Eelon/Publications/Erg-Duke.pdf).